# How to build in ExtJs (javascript) an export file, of a grid, compatible for Excel and Numbers?

Tags: excel, extjs, numbers

I have an application written in Javascript that allows the user to export grids.
These export files are then used with Excel.
We generate these export files in XML format readable by Excel, this allows us to:

- no need to install excel add-in or use excel library
- file format unlike csv file

We now have users running our application on a Mac. But the export files are opened as text by Numbers instead of a spreadsheet.

Is it possible to build the export file in a single format recognized by both (Microsoft Excel, Apple Numbers)? Or in two similar formats to avoid having two completely different implementations?

NB: our application has the front-end written in ExtJs 6, and we want to favor the construction of the file on the client side.

Comment: Excel works fine on a Mac.

Comment: Excel is not installed on the Mac of theses users. They have only Numbers.

Comment: Numbers can open Excel files: https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/open-or-close-spreadsheets-tan753033f43/mac

Comment: Currently our export is generated as Office Open XML format.
But Numbers doesn't support it. 
As quickwin, I don't known if exists a format (easy to generated with javascript language) supported by the both without to have generate a binary format (XLSX)